# Copy reference and concatenate lists

Tags: python, list, reference, concatenation

when I have several objects and put them into a list, the list only holds the references to the objects. I need the same behaviour for lists themselves.

So lets say I have:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
...
```

I want to have *allLists* like this:

```
allLists = [list1, list2, ..., listn]
```

But Python always does this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
...
allLists = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...]
```

I tried to append, insert, concatenate or simply use the + Operator, but Python always copies the content data of each list into *allLists* instead of copying the referencs of *list1* to *listn* and only save the references in *allLists*.

Is it possible, to get only the references of *list1* to *listn* in *allLists*?

Comment: Not directly, no. Perhaps if you said a few words about the actual problem you're trying to solve, we might be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: It is not true that python copies the content.

Comment: as this problem exists in a large project with undocumented code I don't think this would improve clarity...I'm working on a complete new object oriented implementation but for today I have to fix the cold code and get it working^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do things the way you want to. You're going  to need make a new list and then just append your lists individually

```
In [1]: super_list = []
In [2]: list1 = [1,2,3]
In [3]: list2 = [4,5,6]
In [4]: super_list.append(list1)
In [5]: super_list.append(list2)
In [6]: super_list
Out[6]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the obvious:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = [4,5,6]
>>> allLists = [list1, list2]
>>> allLists
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that , but you can use dictionary :

this is what you try :

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = [4,5,6]
>>> newlist=[list1,list2]
>>> newlist
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

use dictionary :

```
>>> dict={'list1' : [1,2,3],'list2' :[4,5,6]}
>>> dict.keys()
['list1', 'list2']
>>> dict['list1']
[1, 2, 3]
```